# GCC openmp support mac os with or without multilib

Tags: macos, gcc, openmp

I've seen advice that suggests that if you want to compile using GCC on a mac you need to install gcc the following way, without multilib.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc6 --without-multilib
```

Here's an example question to that point.

[What does gcc without multilib mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049486/what-does-gcc-without-multilib-mean)

Recently I forgot to follow this advice and just did (I think):

```
brew install gcc
```

This installed much quicker and seem to be working fine. Rereading about the without-multilib option, I seem to remember seeing that this may have been a bug in older versions of GCC.

So my question is, is there any reason why one might prefer the without-multilib option for openmp on a mac, besides file size?