# Can't compile with gcc-4.9

Tags: parallel-processing, gcc4.9

I eventually want to use valgrind to find what is causing the occasional bizarre output in a C program which refines a model against experimental data using OpenMP parallel programming.

To avoid the use of the nominal gcc (ie clang) compiler, I used brew to install gcc-4.9 on my MacPro running Yosemite (OS x 10.10.5). However, when trying to compile my program with gcc-4.9, with or without -fopenmp, I get numerous error messages of the type:

> /var/folders/qc/1j0gr_l48xnfd9001s6tt6f80000gn/T//ccRxnrnU.s:30597:suffix
>   or operands invalid for `movq'

I have no idea what the problem triggering these error messages is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Errr, Yosemite was v10.10, Leopard was v10.5...

Comment: Oops! Thanks Mark. Should have said Yosemite (OS 10.10.5)

Comment: Did you use `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9` as your compiler? What flags did you use when compiling? Have you tried compiling a trivial piece of code? Did you use `brew install gcc-XYZ --without-multilib`?

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help; it's much appreciated. I started with gcc-4.9 on the command line but /usr/local/bin is on my PATH. I had the same problem whether I used either -fopenmp or -Wall flags when compiling. I will try your suggestion of compiling a trivial piece of code. If I remember correctly I simply used brew install gcc@4.9 without anything else.

Comment: Mark, you're clearly well onto solving my problem. Yes, when I try to compile with gcc-4.9 a simple C program with no pragmas, no GSL, no dynamic memory allocation etc I get the same stream of error messages starting with /var !

Comment: Maybe you have updated OSX without updating `Xcode`. Either run `xcode-select --install` again in Terminal, or start up `Xcode` and look for any `Update` buttons in the Preferences or About menu options.

Comment: I upgraded to Yosemite from OS x10.6 and then downloaded xcode 6.3. When just now I tried to run xcode 6.3, it didn't start immediately but first took several minutes to verify and then asked for additional components to download. I then used the Preferences/Downloads to update xcode. After clicking on  check and download now, it said it was installing two updates and now gives a tick by xcode 6.3 which I take to mean it has done all it could. But still a stream of errors when I try to compile the simple C program with gcc-4.9. Should I be upgrading to a higher version of xcode (eg 7.2)?

Comment: Please don't think I necessarily know all the answers;-) All I am suggesting is that you ensure your Xcode is as up-to-date as possible, that you have run `xcode-select --install` after upgrading Xcode, and that you re-install `gcc` with `--without-multilib` and that you re-compile and re-run your app after that. That sequence seems, by experience, to cure most ills - however parts of it may be unnecessary or redundant. Like I said, I do not **know** the answer for certain - if I did, I would put it as an actual answer rather than a comment:-)

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I will do all that you suggest tomorrow.

Comment: I am delighted to report that when I used brew install gcc@4.9 --without-multilib the resulting gcc-4.9 compiled my C program with no error messages even with the -fopenmp flag. My grateful thanks to Mark.

Comment: Excellent news! And good luck with your project. I may summarise the steps in an answer so future readers don't have to wade through the comments.

Comment: Good. So it wasn't a problem with my Xcode, only with my brew install. It would be good to know what the --without-multilib actually means. Thanks again, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

The following summarises what was worked out in the *comments* section and did lead to the issue being resolved. Not all steps may be necessary, but most are probably good practice.

---

**Step 1 - Clean up**

If you have been trying lots of different, potentially incompatible, methods to get OpenMP set up, it is probably a good idea to clean them up first. So, something like:

```
brew rm --force gcc           # or maybe gcc@4.9
```

---

**Step 2 - Update Xcode and Command Line Tools**

If you have upgraded macOS since installing **Xcode**, it is probably advisable to update **Xcode** and its *"Command Line Tools"*

Consider uninstalling and re-installing **Xcode** - it is available for free from the *App Store*.

Update/install the *"Command Line Tools"* after installing/updating with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

---

**Step 3 - Install gcc**

Now, try installing `gcc` afresh, ensuring that you use the `--without-multilib` option:

```
brew install gcc@4.9 --without-multilib
```

---

Hopefully you can now compile OpenMP code with:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc -fopenmp program.c -o program
```

I am unsure **exactly why** the `--without-multilib` option is needed and prefer to quote @hristo-iliev:

> Multilib usually refers to the coexistence of both 64-bit and 32-bit
>   versions of each library so that 32-bit software could be run on
>   64-bit OS. In the GCC case that probably refers to having all GCC
>   runtime libraries in "fat" Mach-O format, i.e. versions for both i386
>   and x86_64 in the same shared library file. It could be that libgomp
>   (the GNU OpenMP runtime library) cannot be built in such a way.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30049486/2836621).

**Keywords**: gcc, g++, GNU Compiler, OpenMP, fopenmp, -fopenmp, Xcode, multilib, Command Line Tools, macOS, OSX, homebrew, brew